# Generate file path in gallery?

Tags: android, filepath

I am using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to generate new directory (or just say a folder). It suppose to store all image generated from my app. However, I found that the folder generated by this method can't be seen in gallery. I have to use EX File Explorer or something else to check that folder. I am wondering how I can create a new directory which can be seen in the gallery?

Comment: If you are creating new content make sure it is indexed by MediaScanner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17391679/833647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because your new content has not been indexed yet by the `MediaScanner`.

`MediaScanner` scans media and places it into the `MediaStore`, an internal database of metadata about media.

If you are creating new content you will need to tell `MediaScanner` that it needs indexing. It should then show up in the gallery.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391679/833647