# Video not shown on Gallery

Tags: android

I have saved the video on SD card but its not showing in gallery

I can see the video in the sd card and its playing

I am using this method to get video uri and save it

```
public static Uri getVideoUri(Context context) {
        Marapreferences marapreferences=Marapreferences.getInstance(context);
        boolean ismedia=marapreferences.isMedia();
        File file = null;

        File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/mara_messenger/videos");
        if (!file2.exists()) {
            file2.mkdirs();
        }


        currentFileName = "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

        imageName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/mara_messenger/videos/" + currentFileName;

        file = new File(imageName);
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        System.out.println("Image uri" + imgUri);
        return imgUri;
    }




File file=new File(uri);
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath()},

                    new String[]{"video/mp4"}, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)

                    {
                              System.out.println("completed");                                             
                              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                              intent.setData(uri);
                              sendBroadcast(intent);                                        
                    }

                    });
```

I can see after scan URI and path but still not showing on gallery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722494/3194316

Comment: Make sure you update the MediaStore by telling the MediaScanner about the new file http://stackoverflow.com/a/17391679/833647

Comment: I am working on s4 its not working here I even tested S4

Comment: I am editing my answer to place scan code