# Can't create a folder in Gallery, external storage

Tags: java, android, android-camera, gallery, photo

I'm new in Android and I've follow this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html and I can't create folder in `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures`.

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getPublicAlbumStorageDir("FileName");
    if (storageDir ==null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry no folder available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return storageDir;
    }
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
    );
    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Someone told me to use `getPublicAlbumStorageDir()` https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#java instead of `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

```
public File getPublicAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) throws IOException {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    Log.i("File", file.getAbsolutePath());
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.e("Error", file.getAbsolutePath());
        file.mkdirs();
        if(!file.exists()){
            Log.e("Error22", file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else{
            Log.i("In", "you are in");
            return file;
        }
        return null;
    }
    return file;
}
```

Here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I've try to found more about this issue and the only working project is on this [site](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/camera/photobasics.html), but some of the actions are old.

I'm using for testing `Android 8.0.0` and also `Android 6.0.0`.

**It's working**
**If you want to make a folder on gallery, this how you should do:**

1. Go to https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath and copy permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml as adding a `FileProvider` inside `<application>` tags. Then inside res or resource, create a folder with the name `xml` and inside make a xml file called `file_paths`, in the file copy what is under `FileProvider` but change `path` to `path="."`.

   > (Don´t forget to ask permissions to the user, if you use it for real).
2. In the same page, above you will find `private void dispatchTakePictureIntent()`, copy that and `static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1`. *`dispatchTakePictureIntent()` is the first thing you need to call, in order to work.*
3. After that, create a `String mCurrentPath` and copy `Private File createImageFile()` from above.
4. Next, copy `public File getPublicAlbumStorageDir(String albumName)` which is above this explanation.
5. If you run it it will show the camera and you can deny or accept the photo you take. However you still have to add a little more code.

   `String REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 2;
   @Override
   protected void onActivity(int requestCode, int requestCode, Intent data){
       if(requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           //Show ImageView here if you want
           galleryAddPic();
       }
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   }`
6. In https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery duplicate `private void galleryAddPic()` and if you want to show the image taken, add this:

   `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

And like so, your image should be in the FolderName you have defined.

I decided to make this small tutorial because I couldn't find the answer for this problem and in Android website is not well explain.

Huge thanks to [greenapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108972/greenapps)! I really appreciate!

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the storage?

Comment: yes, i have edit the thread. @Raúl Pérez López

Comment: i don't see a error. Just a note file providers are needed for api level above marshmallow. Plus, try to have a delay after onActivityResult (use handler delay for that) as sometimes images data is not written for some device for a uri.

Comment: @Killer the images are saving but not in the correct folder https://imgur.com/a/r1j6u, they should be saved in storage/emulated/0/picures not in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app/files/pictures

Comment: Because you are not using `File tempDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`.

Comment: And further you should change path to `path="."`.

Comment: @greenapps and how sould I do it?

Comment: I told you already what you had to do.

Comment: @greenapps on file path change path=".", like this?! Does not work either

Comment: `File tempDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` My god... telll if you now useed it or not. And try.

Comment: `// Error occurred while creating the File
            Toast.makeText(this, "O erro: " + ex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` . My god... are you seeing this toast? Dont only tell that it does not wordk as with that you tell nothing! Is the file creaated or not?

Comment: @greenapps no the file is not created, it only creates on app folder

Comment: `it only creates on app folder` Again unclear! Please tell complete path of that folder.. And why do you post that much code if the only thing is that creating a file fails? Unbelievable.

Comment: @greenapps has I mention in the thread [here](https://prnt.sc/io4mx2), in the red line is the path that is making. I post that much code because I don't want to be unclear about this issue.

Comment: That is not the way you should inform us about used paths. Just write them here. Now you could remove nearly all your code. only the code for `private File createImageFile() throws IOException {` would do. And telling what it should do and what it does instead. Supply all relevant paths. Your only problem first is creating a file. (Not that you should... but  more about that later).

Comment: `it only creates on app folder`. I do not believe that. Please take a file explorer app on your device and browse to that path and you will see.

Comment: @greenapps so I isolated `private File createImageFile()`, on onclick button with try catc. Where it throw exception is `File image = File.createTempFile( imageFileName, ".jpg", algo);` There error is: `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory`

Comment: @greenapps this is what creates https://photos.app.goo.gl/Q03EU7hXf0i7YEI73

Comment: So please remove all other code. And adjust the subject of your post. I'm waiting... And i will not follow your links. Please behave.

Comment: @greenapps I have adjust the post. I'm sorry my first post here.

Comment: Ok. Finally. But react on my suggestions and comments: `it only creates on app folder. I do not believe that. Please take a file explorer app on your device and browse to that path and you will see. `.

Comment: `if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Directory not created");
    }` Completely wrong code. You should only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist yet. And if mkdirs() fails you should return '`null` from that function. `if ( ! file.exists()) if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Directory not created: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
  return null;  }`

Comment: And in the function where you called it be prepared that `null` can be returned. `if (storageDir==null){ Toast(... sorry no folder available... );  return;}`.

Comment: Please adapt your code. Also here. Then tell what happens.

Comment: @greenapps now, have not created app folder in Android/data. And on logs it shows `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Escolinha`

Comment: So you cannot create a folder in external storage. (It's really time you update the subject of your post as all has nothing to do with the Gallery). For reading and writing in external storage you need permissions. Hope you ever heard of them. What did you do to obtain them? Also tell wich Android version you use to test.

Comment: @greenapps I've change it.

Comment: REPEAT: Which Android version is your app running on?

Comment: `android:maxSdkVersion="18"` Better remove.

Comment: `I debug and thorws error when creating File image =` You better remove that too as your code will not come to that point any more now.

Comment: @greenapps I'm using `Android 8.0.0` and `Android 6.0.0`.

Comment: @greenapps is my problem someting related with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391679/9435145 ?

Comment: Please dont let me follow links. Just tell in your own words what you think it is.

Comment: @greenapps so where do I go from here?!

Comment: For Android 6+ its not enough to request those permissions in manifest. You have to add extra code to ask the user to confirm those permissions at runtime.

Comment: @greenapps I'm making user permissions write permissions.

Comment: Cant you read? That is not enough!

Comment: @greenapps sorry, i ask the user to accept or denied permissions

Comment: `if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.e("ERROR", file.getAbsolutePath());
        return null;
    }`  ????? Where is the `mkdirs()`  ??????

Comment: @greenapps it keeps not working.

Comment: My god.. You placed it at the wrong place withoud checking the return value. Reread my comments...i told you exactly how to code it.

Comment: @greenapps I made it work

Comment: @greenapps like this is any good??