# I want save images in gallery click on button

Tags: android, android-intent, media-queries, android-image, android-studio-3.0

I have already tried some code from stack overflow. link mention below

[How to save image in android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859584/how-to-save-image-in-android-gallery)

But that answer is not working on my project. Please help me to find out a solution.

I designed two buttons in the application one for saving images and one for share images.

I have tried a code for download the images.but this code showing me nothing.

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = imageView.getDrawingCache();
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), b ,"image", "image decsription");
```

Now 
I want to share the same image with the intent. I tried this code but it is showing me

> unable to attach media file

my code is below..

```
private void createShareIntent(){
        Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,mImageUrl);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Send "));
    }
```

Please help me to find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two things. Saving an image and sharing an image. It is unclear what goes wrong and what help you ask. A solution for what? Please edit your post.

Comment: Didn't get it, which part is not working the saving part or the sharing one? Seems you have 2 different questions. For the first one, did you add the permissions for your app to access the external storage?

Comment: @Eselfar Both are not working. sharing part showing me error Unable to attach media file.

Comment: [Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156395/cant-create-a-folder-in-gallery-external-storage) see if it works for you

Comment: But I want to save the image in the gallery on button click.Becoz I display my images on the imageView.  so can you please tell me how can  I save that image in gallery.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
//to get the image from the ImageView (say iv)
BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

**Additionally, in order to refresh the gallery and to view the image there:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Also make sure that your app has the storage permission enabled:
Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!**

**Manifest permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file)).    whare you are declard file variable ??

Comment: your code is showing me this error and not saving an image in a gallery

Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Comment: on Which Device you are testing

Comment: Add this android:protectionLevel="signature" in your manifest .

Like:  <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. but this is not working. I tried this.